# On Dropdown Selection, how to fill complete form fields from Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How to fill the complete form input fields from Database based on the value selected from the Dropdown

Example: In a Application, by selecting a client name it fills the complete form input fields with the details stored in the Database.

```
Sample Code:
<select name="client">
 <option value="">-- Select Client Name -- </option>
 <option value="1">John</option>
 <option value="2">Smith</option>                               
</select>

<input name="phone" type="text" value="">
<input name="email" type="text" value="">
<input name="city" type="text" value="">
<textarea name="address"></textarea>
```

All the about input fields need to be filled with values on client name selection.

---

**EDIT:**

I tried with AJAX but couldn't able get the particular variable from the file... below is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#client').change(function() {
            alert();
            var selected = $(this).find(':selected').html();

            $.post('get_details.php', {'client': selected}, function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the `get_details.php` file I am storing different values in different variables, but I didn't understand how to get them to individual variable to main page.

Comment: Use Ajax. Jquery is easy.

Comment: What you have tried so far, to achieve your goal ?

Comment: tried with ajax but couldn't able get particular variable from the file... below is my code

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
  {
   $('#client').change(function()
   {
    alert();
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected').html();
    $.post('get_details.php', {'client': selected}, function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data);
    });
   }); 
  });
    </script>

in the get_details.php file iam storing different values in different variables, but i didn't understand how to get them to individual variable to main page

Comment: You need to add the code formatted above, it's pretty unreadable.  Assuming your php is returning correctly, you need to set the values of the relevant inputs: http://api.jquery.com/val/. I'm not sure what you expect $('#result') to do, that doesn't correlate to anything in your html.

Comment: I don't know how to use jquery to help you but if you are okay with actual ajax code, I can help.

Comment: Sure @GideonAppoh ... Anything is okay for me !!

Comment: @Brian result will be added to input field in the HTML

Answer (score 5):

This is a just a basic jQuery example that *calls itself* (the top portion of the script is active when a `$_POST` is made), which I have named `index.php` as indicated in the `url` of the jQuery AJAX. You can use two separate pages to do this if you want. Just separate out the PHP from the HTML/Javascript and change the `url: '/index.php'`:

```
<?php
// This is where you would do any database call
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Send back a jSON array via echo
    echo json_encode(array("phone"=>'123-12313',"email"=>'test@test.com','city'=>'Medicine Hat','address'=>'556 19th Street NE'));
    // Exit probably not required if you
    // separate out your code into two pages
    exit;
}
?>

<form id="tester">
    <select name="client" id="client">
        <option value="">-- Select Client Name -- </option>
        <option value="1">John</option>
        <option value="2">Smith</option>                               
    </select>
    <input name="phone" type="text" value="">
    <input name="email" type="text" value="">
    <input name="city" type="text" value="">
    <textarea name="address"></textarea>
</form>

<!-- jQuery Library required, make sure the jQuery is latest -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // On change of the dropdown do the ajax
        $("#client").change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                    // Change the link to the file you are using
                    url: '/index.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    // This just sends the value of the dropdown
                    data: { client: $(this).val() },
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Parse the jSON that is returned
                        // Using conditions here would probably apply
                        // incase nothing is returned
                        var Vals    =   JSON.parse(response);
                        // These are the inputs that will populate
                        $("input[name='phone']").val(Vals.phone);
                        $("input[name='email']").val(Vals.email);
                        $("input[name='city']").val(Vals.city);
                        $("textarea[name='address']").val(Vals.address);
                    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No problem! Make sure you mark your question as answered so you don't have others coming to try and solve an already-solved question. Cheers

Comment: @Aswathy what do you mean? As noted, my example is calling itself. When the Ajax runs, it calls itself and since it’s send a post request, the top part of the page (php portion) runs then exits so the rest of the page doesn’t also run and mess up the json.

Comment: @Aswathy Also, it’s not really a common thing to do, but it works. I would recommend calling a different page, unless you are doing a rewrite.

Comment: ok..ok...thanks for your reply.This is my careless mistake..sorry..:)

Answer (score -3):

When you made ajaxCall return data in json format  like

```
json_encode(array("phone"=>'123-12313',"email"=>'test@test.com','city'=>'Medicine Hat','address'=>'556 19th Street NE'));
```

above shown

then parse it in jQuery and put the value in different selectors like

```
 var Vals    =   JSON.parse(response);
 // These are the inputs that will populate
 $("input[name='phone']").val(Vals.phone);
```

above shown.

Comment: Why are you copying parts of my answer?? That's weird man. Word for word copy, that's even worse!

Comment: I made a ton of notations for the OP, I don't think your additions are that much more clarifying than what I wrote...