# Populate form from SQL table after user selects from select box

Tags: php, html, mysql

On a SQL db table, there are details of people. At first I want the user to select a name from the select box. Then when the user selects a name, I want the other data from the table (address, phone number) to be shown on text fields. How can I do this?

I am populating an HTML select box from a SQL database like this:

```
<select name="assoc">
        <?php 
            $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM profiles ");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
            <?php echo "<option value='" . $row['display_name'] . "'>" . $row['display_name'] . "</option>"; } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: you will need to create another view with the filed and submit the select form redirecting to that view, or use ajax to change the current page o select change

Comment: @madalinivascu, I am not very good with ajax :(

Comment: then go with page redirect to another view

Comment: @madalinivascu what do you mean by "another view"? You mean include a submit button and send the selected data via POST or GET?

Comment: yes that is what i mean, but you will need to submit the data on select change event which needs javascript

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825656/on-dropdown-selection-how-to-fill-complete-form-fields-from-database